# Constructing a string from fields in UUID object

Tags: c, string, uuid

I have the following code for printing a UUID which works fine:

```
void puid(uuid_t u)
{
    int i;

    printf("%8.8x-%4.4x-%4.4x-%2.2x%2.2x-", u.time_low, u.time_mid,
    u.time_hi_and_version, u.clock_seq_hi_and_reserved,
    u.clock_seq_low);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("%2.2x", u.node[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Example output:

```
22b31d0d-4814-56e9-ba30-6c23d328deaf
```

How would I go about constructing a char string to save the above output in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about :

```
char uuid[40];

sprintf(uuid, "%8.8x-%4.4x-%4.4x-%2.2x%2.2x-%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x", 
u.time_low, u.time_mid, u.time_hi_and_version, u.clock_seq_hi_and_reserved,
u.clock_seq_low, u.node[0], u.node[1], u.node[2], u.node[3], u.node[4], u.node[5]);

printf("%s\n", uuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use   [sprintf()](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=sprintf)

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```

**Write formatted data to string**

Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by str.

Answer (score 0):

UUID is **36 characters length** always. so declare a char array of 37 chars.

and use `sprintf()` for forming string.

See definition section.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier